# Strength check between medium size and large size

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, creature-size

Suppose a medium size human with shield mastery attempts to prone a warhorse.

Human is medium, warhorse is large.

How will you settle the check? Does large have advantage on strength checks against medium size?

Or

They contest as normal with neither having advantage?

Answer (score 14):

From the PHB p. 195

> **Shoving a Creature**
>
> Using the Attack action, you can make a special melee attack to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you. If you’re able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces 
>   one of them.
>
> **The target of your shove must be no more than one size larger than you**, and it must be within your reach. You make a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics)  check (the target chooses the ability to use). If you win the contest, you either knock the target prone or push it 5 feet away from you.

As long as the target is only one size larger, no one gets advantage or disadvantage.

Comment: Odd, 5e doesn't seem to have the extra +4 or whatever for the target having multiple legs that existed in 3.5?  huh ... Cow tipping is back boys!!  :)

Comment: @Ditto: And Dwarves, let's tip dwarves!

Comment: @Ditto 5e doesn't have little pluses and minuses sprinkled around. If it seems like there *should* be a plus/minus to a situation (like here), then it should be done with (dis)advantage.

Comment: @Yotus one thing I'd suggest adding: before looking up the shove rules it's within the DM's purview whether or not to even call for that contest. *I.e.* the DM can think: (a) player narrates what their character's doing, (b) *is it possible and should I call for a check/contest/attack?* (*cf.* DMG p.237), (c) *what* check should it be? (Which third part you perfectly answer above.)